# How to get the point index in the path of TubeBufferGeometry ? (three.js)

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I have created the TubeBufferGeometry. The code is following:

```
var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( pointArray, false, "centripetal"); 
var geometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( curve, pointArray.length, tubeRadius, radiusSegments, closed );
```

To get the interested point, I used the  Raycaster.intersectObject(), I can get the following results.

> distance – distance between the origin of the ray and the intersection
>
> point – point of intersection, in world coordinates
>
> face – intersected face
>
> faceIndex – index of the intersected face
>
> object – the intersected object
>
> uv - U,V coordinates at point of intersection

Now I can get the intersected point position in TubeBufferGeometry when moving the mouse.

How can I find the nearest point in the pointArray to the intersected point？

Should I convert the coordination of the intersected point into world vector?

Many thanks.

Comment: Intersections are returned sorted by distance, closest first. Just take first element of array, point will be returned in world coordinates.

Comment: Thanks Alex. How can I highlight the tubularSegment when mouse on the tubeGeometry?

Comment: tubularSegments — Integer - The number of segments that make up the tube, default is 64.  
I set tubularSegments as the number of points in the curve.

Comment: Thanks. I find the answer in https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-get-the-point-index-in-the-path-of-tubebuffergeometry-when-moving-mouse-on-the-tubebuffergeometry/6657/9 .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/4bghcdew  This example is helpful for my answer.